# How to pass a layer from one model to another when two models are training on different data simultaneously?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, keras-layer

I have two models that train on two different datasets. But I want to train the second model with different data whose initial point would be the last dropout layer from the first model (Image attached shows the architecture of two models). How would I be able to do this?

[model architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW8zF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what framework you are working with, but I know this is possible with Pytorch. not sure about TensorFlow or the others. After training your first model you can construct the second model's architecture and take the weights from the first model and assign the respective layers layer by layer. If you have some code sample I can help you further. assuming you are using Pytorch you can use something like in [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/loading-a-specific-layer-from-checkpoint/52725/2).

Comment: I am using Keras but I could switch to PyTorch to implement this. I have one more question about this. Is it possible to implement those two models which train on two different sets of datasets simultaneously? Because I do not want to just use the weights after completely training the first model. I want to use the weights of the first model from every epoch and then train the second model with it.

Comment: What you're doing looks similar to multi task learning. and from my experience with that I don't know any straight forward way to "simultaneously" train both models with different datasets while sharing model weights.